# XSLT - removing empty nodes

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am using the below xslt to remove namespaces. How can it be enhanced to remove empty tags as well?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can strip any empty elements as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space())]"/>
```

Also your strip-namespaces template does not account for attributes, so you may want to extend it as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
  <xsl:for-each select="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```